# angular 2 passing parameters through service rather than router parameters

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

When passing parameters from component to component, we can use the following

```
  onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    this.router.navigate( ['HeroDetail', { id: hero.id }] );
  }
```

But when the data to be passed around is complex then the above will make the URL looked messy. I tried to pass parameters through a service at parent level and it works fine. Then `onSelect()` becomes

```
  onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    this._heroService._dataStore.hero = hero;
    this.router.navigate( ['HeroDetail' );
  }
```

In the `ngInit()` I retrieved `id` from `this._heroService._dataStore.hero.id`. This make the URL much cleaner.

My questions is that is there any downside of this approach? If yes what do people get around those cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one downside would be that you won't be able to refresh the page and persist the data like you would if it were a url parameter.

Comment: very good point. page reload destroys the service data. Using local storage is better?